# grecaptcha is not defined [REACT]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I'm doing a project in *React* with *Typescript* and I have the problem **"Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined"**. I searched for alternative solutions but found nothing effective yet. My unsuccessful solution attempt: I installed grecaptcha (npm install --save @types/grecaptcha), however the problem remains.

````
const handleQuery = () => {
    if (id === "upload-file" && sendFileFlag) {
      // @ts-ignore
      const selectedFile = generalRegister.file[0];

      grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        grecaptcha
          .execute(
            "https://SITE_KEY",
            { action: "submit" }
          )
          .then(function (token: string) {
            submitFile(selectedFile, token);
          });
      });
  
    }
  };
```
````